# Determine FOSC of PIC16F1516 codebase

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am doing reverse engineer of the codebase of uC PIC16F1516 and looking for FOSC to determine TIMER overflow count value.
I can see in the code,

```
// SCS FOSC; IRCF 500KHz_MF; 
OSCCON = 0x38;
```

And

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ  4000000
```

May I please know the crystal oscillator frequency that the TIMER would have to use to overflow count computation?

Comment: What is "FOSC"?  I've been working with micro's since the early 80's and coding professionally since 1990.  I've also used that particular PIC processor for hydroponic control systems, but I have no idea what is meant by "FOSC".  I think your title should contain the question you ask at the end of your post.

Comment: You do have the data sheet, don't you? What did you find there?

Comment: You need to dig deeper and find what is set in the configuration words for the FOSC. Is it set to use the internal oscillator?

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to read the datasheet for you, what did you find when you read the datasheet?  what part of that documentation did you not understand?   we have no access to your pcb documentation if it is an external oscillator (without doing your research for you I wouldnt know if that part even supports an external oscillator).   what is the actual question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear, but I guess that FOSC (frequency of oscillator) is 4 Mhz (i.e., _XTAL_FREQ defined in the source). The OSCCON  register can then divide that clock and sets other things, so look well, but your question is answered by 4 Mhz.